# Post shout without venue on Foursquare

Tags: foursquare, checkin

It used to be possible to post a chekin without a venue, which would result in a "shout" being posted to Foursquare. This has stopped working. Is it possible to do this anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per this announcement, it's no longer possible: https://groups.google.com/group/foursquare-api/browse_thread/thread/231fcc783f5c592f